# Jersey ApplicationPath not working - 404 Error

Tags: java, glassfish, jersey-2.0

This is not a duplicate question. My current setup does not use web.xml's like many of the questions on here, nor do I use maven or gradle so I have no missing dependencies. I define my ApplicationPath("test") and my Path("Service"). Both of these classes reside in the same package: website. I've tried using ResourceConfig instead of extending Application but this also did not work

```
@ApplicationPath("/test")

public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        HashSet h = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        h.add(Service.class);
        return h;
    }
```

Also tried

```
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public MyApplication() {
            register(Service.class)
            packages("website");
        }
}
```

Service Class

```
@Path("Service")
public class Service {

    FormResource formResource = new FormResource();
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    public void setForm(@FormParam("doctor") String doctor, @FormParam("message") String message, @Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Form form = new Form();
        //with post parameters
        form.setDoctor(doctor);
        form.setMessage(message);
        formResource.setForm(form);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/form.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    @GET
    public void redirect(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/form.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

Neither of these work. I'm trying to access it at localhost:8080/mywar/test/Service but receive a 404 error. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: where is `Path("Service")`?

Comment: In a separate file in the same package

Comment: Add the service file so we can see what's wrong

Comment: Okay I have added the service class